Python tcpserver error "connection reset by peer" when setting the stream buffering to 0
I'm using the TCPServer to communicate with clients, and use the stream created using the socket.makfile("rwb") call. If the communication is only from client to the server, everything works fine. However,if the mutual communication is needed, I need to create the stream with the option of "buffering=0" (socket.makfile(buffering=0)), otherwise the message sent from the server to the client could not be received on time. This brings another problem that when the client (even with only message passing from client to server only) finishes, the server side will have the error "connection reset by peer".
Having been banging my head against the wall for this problem. No clue how to fix this. Any suggestion is appreciated!
